# confusion-silver light- is data access using simple sql and layout using master pages possible?

Tags: silverlight

I am a little confused

- is there a simple way an sql connection to db can be used to manipulate data using c#
- can a master page and child page be used?

or is there a different way for the above two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using a separate Silverlight application for each page then the concept of master pages and child pages doesn't apply.

The way I look at Silverlight (and to an extent Flash) is that you are using desktop type designs but presenting them on the web. The Silverlight application is a self contained thing that can communicate with the web page, but it holds an internal model of the system and displays different views depending on what you want to do.

The best way to interact with a database is using RIA services. These are designed for use with Silverlight applications and enable the asynchronous communications you need for remote access across the web.